# How to keep only numbers and hyphen in string?

Tags: php

My text is not in English:

```
יום שלישי, 23 ינואר, 2018 06:00 - 07:00
```

I want to save only the time:

```
06:00 - 07:00
```

And then separate the hours between - , to do:

$echo starttime;

$echo endtime;

Comment: Regex is your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a regex to solve this, and a good one would be something like:

```
/([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/
```

This would be combined with **[`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)** to break up all of the results, and store them in an array, with something like the following:

```
<?php

$string = 'יום שלישי, 23 ינואר, 2018 06:00 - 07:00';
preg_match_all("/([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/", $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Which returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 06:00
    [1] => 07:00
)
```

And can be seen live **[here](https://3v4l.org/iBSCO)**.

From here, you would just assign the results to new variables:

```
$start = $matches[0][0];
$end = $matches[0][1];
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @Ovsidian Age Perfect! Thanks a lot :) and I knew a new site: 3v4l.org

Answer (score 2):

Other than using regex .. If your string is always formatted the same .. No need to overcomplicate things .. Just strip out the times using `substr`  --  Then `explode` on the `-` (spaces included).

```
<?php
$string = '07:00 - 06:00 ... ... ... ';


$times = substr($string, 0, 13); // assuming your string format is always the same
$timeArr = explode(' - ', $times);

$starttime = $timeArr[1];
$endtime = $timeArr[0];

echo $starttime . ' - ' . $endtime;
?>
```

Comment: If the format is consistent including times with two-digit hours, you don't even need to explode. you can just do two substr calls.